# Silverlight - Routing question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following route in global.asax:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "IdeaShort",
            "Idea/{id}",
            new { PortalID = NEOGOV_Ideas.Models.Util.DefaultPortal().PortalID, IdeaType = "All", controller = "Home", action = "Idea", id = "" });
```

one problem - PortalID and IdeaType is linked with Idea, so I should get Idea from id before set PortalID and IdeaType. How to do it? Thanks

Comment: Generally, it is a very low-quality question. My answer is based on just a wild guess of what you're trying to do - could you provide more details, please?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't make PortalID and IdeaType incoming parameters of your action, but rather determine them inside the action method:

```
public ActionResult Idea(int id)
{
    var PortalID = GetPortalID(id); //get PortalID here
    var IdeaType = GetIdeaType(id); //get IdeaType here
    //go on with the whole set of parameters you need
}
```

Comment: I need to describe it in route table because I create links on view using Route values